# valueFactory in Concurrent dictionary

Tags: c#, delegates, func, concurrentdictionary

I am writing a winform program to test the C# concurrent dictionary with below class:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int X = 10;

    public Class1(int x)
    {
        X = x;
        Debug.WriteLine("Class1 Created");
    }
}
```

and below button code:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Class1>();

        Func<Class1> valueFactory = () => 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Factory Called");
            return new Class1(5);
        };

        var temp = dict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory());
        Debug.WriteLine(temp.X);
        temp.X = 20;

        var temp2 = dict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory());
        Debug.WriteLine(temp2.X);
    }
```

I have noticed that the valueFactory method has always been executed and Class1 constructor been called twice even the key already exists in dict after the first GetorAdd method.

However, if I change the Func definition to

```
Func<int, Class1> valueFactory = (k) => 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Factory Called");
            return new Class1(5);
        };
```

and call the GetorAdd method like below:

```
var temp = dict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory);
```

The program works in the desired way as it did not call Class1 constructor in the second call. I suspect it is because I passed a delegate valueFactory instead of function call `valueFactory()` to the GetorAdd method.
I wonder if there is a detail explanation in what is happening under the hood and I also don't understand why I can't not pass in valueFactory as delegate if my Func definition is anything other than `Func<int, Class1`(the same definition as the dictionary)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
var temp = dict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory());
...
var temp2 = dict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory());
```

You are actually invoking `valueFactory` ***before*** calling [dict.GetOrAdd()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378674(v=vs.110).aspx). So it's normal that it gets called every time. Sure, the new instance of `Class1` returned by the 2nd invocation to `valueFactory()` is ultimately not useful, but it got created nonetheless.

In contrast, when you do:

```
var temp = dict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory);
...
var temp2 = dict.GetOrAdd(1, valueFactory);
```

... you are actually using a different overload of the method [GetOrAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx), where you pass a reference to the delegate `valueFactory` without invoking it yourself.  The `GetOrAdd()` method then decides if it needs to invoke `valueFactory` or not based on whether the key is found in the dictionary.

[ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd Method (TKey, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) doc:

> Adds a key/value pair to the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` by using the specified function, ***if the key does not already exist.***

In this case, it doesn't need to invoke it a 2nd time, because it finds the key the 2nd time you call `GetOrAdd()`.

---

However, please note that passing in the `valueFactory` as a delegate to `GetOrAdd` doesn't guarantee that it won't get called twice.  This is especially true in multi-threaded scenarios.  Notice what the documentation on [ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd Method (TKey, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx) also says about this:

> If you call `GetOrAdd` simultaneously on different threads, `addValueFactory` may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call.